# Как получить хэндел драйвера в системе и записать в его память

Tags: c++, kernel

Я хочу получить информацию о модуле в системе.
Допустим, есть драйвер в системе Example.sys мне нужно достать image base,size этого модуля.

Comment: image base,size - к хендлу не имеют никакого отношения. И даже image base не означает что именно по этому адресу будет загружен драйвер.

Comment: Мне просто получить информацию о драйвере нужно, который загружен в системе

Comment: image base,size - не является информацией о драйвере в том понимании в котором эту информацию даёт WMI и API драйверов. это информация "для взлома" скорее всего.

Comment: Окей, тогда как получить их?